# python: printing __dict__ : is it possible to print in the same order as what's listed in the class?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Sorry, probably silly question but can't find the answer.. Context is I'm new to python and doing a simple rpg. Class is going to have some basic rpg attributes like

```
class Character(Card):
    def __init__(self, str, dex, con, int, wis, char):
        self.str = str
        self.dex = dex
        self.con = con
        self.int = int
        self.wis = wis
        self.char = char
```

Since I'll be assigning the values depending on the character class, I wanted to make a generic debug method  to print these out for an given class later.  My question is: is there a simple way to print these out in order later (str, dex, con...).

#### I' about to go with a basic

```
def printClass(self):
    attrs = an.__dict__
    print ', ' '\n'.join("%s: %s" % item for item in attrs.items())
```

which prints them out in now particular order
dex: 2, 
int: 4, 
char: 6, 
wis: 5, 
str: 1, 
con: 3

but if i overlooked something to keep it in order, I'd love the help/advice

*Edit:  To clarify if i made rogue = Character(1,2,3,4,5,6), i want to print out rogue.str, rogue.dex  (in the order listed in the class:   str, dex, con, int, wis, char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but here is another option. As you said you wanted *a generic debug method*, I guess you want to print attributes and its values. So a possible way to handle this, would be implementing the [`__str__(self)`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method for the class `Character`

```
class Character(object): # Changed this since I don't know how class 'Card' looks like
    def __init__(self, str, dex, con, int, wis, char):
        self.str = str
        self.dex = dex
        self.con = con
        self.int = int
        self.wis = wis
        self.char = char

    def __str__(self):
        return "str: {}, dex: {}, con: {}, int: {}, wis: {}, char: {}".format(self.str, self.dex, self.con, self.int, self.wis, self.char)

# Testing
list_of_characters = [Character(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "A"), Character(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, "B")]

for e in list_of_characters:
    print e
```

**Output:**

```
str: 1, dex: 2, con: 3, int: 4, wis: 5, char: A
str: 9, dex: 8, con: 7, int: 6, wis: 5, char: B
```

**Edit:**

Note that you **must not use Python types as name of variables** in other words, don't use `str` or `int` as variable names. Call them something else.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thanks (and thanks for the tip on variables)

Answer (score 2):

Try making the order a list and then printing then out in that order:

```
def printClass(self, order):
    attrs = an.__dict__
    for i in order:
        print attrs[i]
```

order could be `['foo', 'bar']`...

You could define order for each class and then just use `an.order` instead of order

Comment: This won't guarantee the order, as dict objects in python do not even preserve order.

Comment: @noa: Yes it will, because it prints in the order of the `order` list, not the order of the dict.

Comment: I'd go with `getattr` instead of `__dict__`, in case you want to change how the attribute lookup works later.

Comment: I see what you're saying. It's confusing since you don't use OP's values.

Comment: @noa, this adds an order to be printed in. That's the whole for loop thing. The order must be defined by the programmer, not python.

Answer (score 1):

Python dict doesn't preserve order. So the short answer is no, you can't print your attribute dict in order. But, may be it will be helpful, you can sort keys before printing:

```
def printClass(self):
    attrs = an.__dict__
    print ', ' '\n'.join("%s: %s" % item for item in sorted(attrs.items(), key=lambda i: i[0]))
```

It will print: char: 6, con: 3, dex: 2, int: 4, str: 1, wis: 5